# combine two (or more..) multi-dimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a query that I run several times with different parameters.  I am using an xml parser to return the results to jQuery.

I can't seem to find a way to combine the results on the first 'node' without overwriting the first entry.

Simplified code sample:

```
$temp1 = returnArray(0);

$temp2 = returnArray(1);

$data = array_merge($temp1, $temp2);

print_r($data);

function returnArray($switch)
{
    if($switch == 0)
    {
        $data['data']['first'] = "something";
    } else {
        $data['data']['second'] = "something ELSE";
    }
    return $data;
}
```

results in printing out `Array ( [data] => Array ( [second] => something ELSE ) )` - $temp2 is overwriting $temp1.  I understand this to be the default behavior of array_merge(), which is confusing to me.

I have also tried doing something like `$data = $temp1+$temp2;` or...

```
$data = returnArray(0);

$data += returnArray(1);
```

prints `Array ( [data] => Array ( [first] => something ) )`

or...

```
$data = returnArray(0);

$data .= returnArray(1);
print_r($data);
```

prints `ArrayArray`

I ended up hacking this together:

```
$data['data'] = returnArray(0);
$data['data'] = returnArray(1);

function returnArray($switch){
  if($switch == 0) return Array('first' => 'something');
  else return Array('second' => 'something else');
}
```

Which i'm not all that happy with... Although it gets the job done in this case, it won't be all that applicable in the future when a more complex situation occurs.

**Is there a better way to take two associative, multi-dimensional arrays and combine them without overwriting?**

EDIT:

I'd like the method to be reusable, extensible and be able to handle 2+ arrays with 2+ dimensions.

Comment: You want to pass them through a function first to determine the contents of the array and then merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP actually provides a function called [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) which is used exactly in this type of scenario. From the [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#refsect1-function.array-merge-recursive-description):

> **`array_merge_recursive()`** merges the
>   elements of one or more arrays
>   together so that the values of one are
>   appended to the end of the previous
>   one. It returns the resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same
>   string keys, then the values for these
>   keys are merged together into an
>   array, and this is done recursively,
>   so that if one of the values is an
>   array itself, the function will merge
>   it with a corresponding entry in
>   another array too. If, however, the
>   arrays have the same numeric key, the
>   later value will not overwrite the
>   original value, but will be appended.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$ar1 = array("color" => array("favorite" => "red"), 5);
$ar2 = array(10, "color" => array("favorite" => "green", "blue"));
$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [color] => Array
        (
            [favorite] => Array
                (
                    [0] => red
                    [1] => green
                )

            [0] => blue
        )

    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
)
```

Comment: thank you =)  I glanced over array_merge_recursive() but upon first read it didn't seem like what I wanted.  I stand corrected!